# MongoCursorNotFoundException -Query failed with error code -5

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

We are getting the following exception.

```
com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: Query failed with error code -5 and error message 'Cursor 43249415092 not found on server xx.xx.xx.xx:27017' 
        at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.receiveMessage(GetMoreProtocol.java:115)
        at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:68)
        at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:37)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:155)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:219)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.getMore(DefaultServerConnection.java:194)
        at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:197)
        at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:93)
        at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:152)
```

We are unable to find the root cause since we are getting this exception rarely.

> We also observed that the application is  unable to read from cursor
>   but no exception is thrown.

In cases where no exception is thrown,we took the thread dump and found that the thread  reading from mongo is in RUNNABLE state.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:85)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:503)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:221)
        at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:102)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:416)
        at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.receiveMessage(GetMoreProtocol.java:112)
        at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:68)
        at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:37)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:155)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:219)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.getMore(DefaultServerConnection.java:194)
        at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:197)
        at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:93)
        at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:152)
```

please help me in finding the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Normally, the cursor times out after some time. You can override that using collection.find().noCursorTimeout(true).iterator();

Comment: But if the inactivity period on the cursor is greater than 10 min(for java driver),then only it times out.But our application reads immediately

Comment: The OP says this exception occurs rarely. Without seeing the code and the environment it runs, it is hard to narrow the root cause.

Comment: @notionquest  thank you. I tried noCursorTimeOut previously and it works.But I want to know why the thread is in RUNNABLE state. If it fails to read,it should throw some error right?

Comment: Are you using a replicaset? maybe one of the secondaries is out of sync in some of its data

Comment: yes,we are using replica set  and We configured read preference  as PRIMARY_PREFERED..how does out of sync secondary causes this issue?

Comment: @notionquest and others: how would I disable the cursor timeout if I'm tied to Mongo Java Driver 3.2.2? I see `FindOptions.noCursorTimeout(...)`, but the `noCursorMethod(...)` method is not available on `DBCursor` until version 3.9, and there seems to be no way of extracting and modifying the `FindOptions` of an existing an existing `DBCursor` in the 3.2.2 API (other than reflection, which I'd like to avoid). What would be the equivalent 3.2.2 API code for disabling the cursor timeout?

Comment: BTW, I'm seeing this for a slow, non-indexed `$where` query over a collection of ~130 million documents. The data just trickles in slowly, and there maybe long periods of inactivity on the cursor, where the database engine scans many documents but does not find a match. In my case, I was expecting about 150K hits, but after ~120K matching documents I hit a long stretch where no documents were matching and the cursor timed out.

Comment: @Jaipal did you find any solution for this or it resolved using noCursorTimeout(), please spare some time to post your answer, it helps

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I met the same issue. After long time research, I figured out it. In my scenario, I have 4 mongos, which behind a load balance(return the mongos IP address randomly). In my connection string, I use the load balance host as the address of the mongoDB cluster .

When the app start, the mongoDB driver create a `server` with a connection pool. In the connection pool, there are mixed connections coming from 4 mongos.

When you query a large data(large than the `batchSize`), The first batch data comes from mongos A, then when the following batch request is pushed, the connection **may** connect to mongos B/C or D([source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/b2f9144486371774be51562afa7da2aa6b9746cf/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/internal/operation/QueryBatchCursor.java#L266)). They can't find the cursor of course. So, the `MongoCursorNotFoundException` is thrown.

### How to handle it?

Do not use balance host in your connection string. use all mongos IP address instead. Let mongoDB driver itself to balance the request.

**WRONG**: `mongodb://your.load.balance.host:27000/yourDB?connectTimeoutMS=60000&minPoolSize=100&maxPoolSize=100&waitqueuemultiple=20&waitqueuetimeoutms=60000`

**RIGHT**: `mongodb://10.0.0.1:27017,10.0.0.2:27017,10.0.0.3:27017,10.0.0.4:27017/yourDB?connectTimeoutMS=60000&minPoolSize=100&maxPoolSize=100&waitqueuemultiple=20&waitqueuetimeoutms=60000`

There is a better solution: You can configure a unique and dedicated host for each mongos, then modify the **RIGHT** connection string: replace the IP address by this host.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me? Should in that case not only the cursor be remembered but also on which host it is valid? But thanks for the research to give me some clue with that error message.